# Matching of a valid and effective user id

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
    printf("real uid: %d\n", getuid());
    printf("effective uid: %d\n", geteuid());
    return 0;
}
```

This is a C program that prints a valid and effective user ID to the screen at startup. It has the following access rights.

```
 -rwsrwxr-x 1 root   root   8780 jul 27 14:39 uid_demo
```

Since there is an s flag and the root creator, it should be run by any user as an administrator, which means different ids will be output, but for some reason they are always the same. I really need to understand why this is so and how to fix it. OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS x86_64.

Comment: Is your executable stored on an NFS filesystem?  If so, move it to a local filesystem.

Comment: the file is on my machine

Comment: Is it on a filesystem with the `nosuid` option enabled? (Or maybe one without the `suid` option; I don't remember what the default is)

Comment: How can I find out? I've been surfing the Internet and haven't found anything about this option

Comment: /dev/sda3 /mnt/sda3 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0

I looked through the fstab directory

/mnt/sda3/ is really a directory, the directory where the program is stored

Comment: That's it, I figured it out. everything is working now, thank you very much!